# On a ubuntu server,run Node.js app and Wordpress together

Tags: node.js, wordpress, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I'm planning to serve blog.mydomain.com on the same server with my node.js app called mydomain.com.

Is it possible to run these together on the same server ? How can I do that with the usage of Nginx ? Can wordpress and node.js app have the same port if they run together ?
It would be great if someone give me a hint to start or any share any resources for me to read.

Answer (score 0):

Create two different nginx conf files for main domain and subdomain like:

1.For main domain which will proxy pass to your node app running on 1234 port

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.com -`

> ```
> server {
>   server_name mydomain.com;
>
>   access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log;
>   error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.error.log;
>
>   location / {
>       proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
>
>   }
>
> }
> ```

2. For subdomain which will proxy pass to your wordpress service running on 5678 port

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog.mydomain.com -`

> server {
>         server_name mydomain.com;
>
> ```
>   access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log;
>   error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.error.log;
>
>   location / {
>       proxy_pass http://localhost:5678;
>
>   }
>
> }
> ```